# is better written in dot notation after function object constructor

Tags: angularjs, jslint, jshint

I have the following code that generates a warning in jshint:

> ['$inject'] is better written in dot notation

```
function Config () {
}

/* jshint -W069 */
Config['$inject'] = ['$routeProvider'];
```

However, the following works as expected (warning silenced):

```
var Config = {}  
/* jshint -W069 */
Config['$inject'] = ['$routeProvider'];
```

How can I use a function to build my object and still be able to silence the warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice in my case was to turn on the following flag for the closure compiler:

> angular_pass: true

and use the following annotation:

```
/**
 * @description App configuration
 * @param {!angular.$routeProvider} $routeProvider
 * @constructor
 * @ngInject
 */
```

Therefore we do not need to use the following

```
Config['$inject'] = ['$routeProvider'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write it in dot notation:

```
Config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
```

JSHint raises that warning when you're using a valid identifier as the member identifier in a square-bracket-style member expression. There's no reason to do so - the dot notation is shorter.

---

If that's not an option (as it appears from your comments) you could try wrapping the relevant code in a function. JSHint appears to only obey the directive when it appears in function scope. For example:

```
(function () {
    function Config() { /* ... */ }
    /* jshint -W069 */
    Config['$inject'] = ['$routeProvider'];
}());
```

Comment: What does the "compilation" do? How does the code look after that process? No minification process should rename property identifiers.

Comment: The closure compiler advanced compilation does..! :)

Comment: @Nicolas - Oh yeah. I forget about Closure, I gave up on it ages ago and use UglifyJS now instead! I've updated the answer with a possible solution, but it doesn't look like there's a nicer way to do this unfortunately.